# PHP Restrict multiple hits on the callback URL

Tags: php

I'm trying to integrate some third-party payment service in PHP. While processing the transaction, I redirect the customer to the third-party generated URL where the customer does the processing, and after a successful transaction, there's a "DONE" button on which the customer clicks, and the customer is redirected back to my provided callback URL.
Sometimes customer clicks the "DONE" button multiple times before the redirect happens and I'm getting multiple hits on my callback URL.
To handle that, I made some changes in the code but that's not working every time.

**Callback Controller:**

```
<?php
try {
    switch ($action) {
        case 'action_1':
            // some code...
            break;

        case 'paymentResponseHandler':
            $transactionId = request()->get('txn_id');
            $publicToken   = request()->get('public_token');
            $cacheKey      = $transactionId . '_cache';

            if (isValidAndActiveTxn($transactionId)) {
                if (!empty($publicToken) && isValidToken($publicToken)) {
                    echo "";
                    ob_flush();
                    flush();
                    if (!connection_aborted()) {
                        if (\Cache::me()->get($cacheKey) != $publicToken) {
                            \Cache::me()->set($cacheKey, $publicToken, 60);
                            $this->paymentService->processTrasactionPayment($transactionId, $publicToken);
                        } else {
                            log_info("Transaction already processed for Public Token: {$publicToken}");
                        }
                    } else {
                        log_info("Multiple Connection Aborted for Public Token: {$publicToken}");
                    }
                } else {
                    log_info("Invalid Payment Token {$publicToken}");
                    return 'Invalid Payment Token';
                }
            } else {
                log_info("Invalid Transaction {$transactionId}");
                return 'Invalid Transaction';
            }
            break;

        default:
            // some code...
            break;
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Exception handling code...
}
```

**Payment Service:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Services\Payment;

class PaymentService
{
    // some code...

    public function processTrasactionPayment($transactionId, $publicToken): void
    {
        try {
            log_info("processTrasactionPayment() initiated", ['transactionId' => $transactionId, 'publicToken' => $publicToken]);
            $apiResponse = $this->callSomeApi($transactionId, $publicToken);

            log_info("API call done.", ['apiResponse' => $apiResponse]);

            if (!empty($apiResponse) && $apiResponse['response']) {
                require PAGE_PATH . "payments/header.php";
                require PAGE_PATH . "payments/pre-loader.php";
                require PAGE_PATH . "payments/post-payment-process.php";
                require PAGE_PATH . "payments/footer.php";
                log_info("Success page loaded.");
            } else {
                log_error('Transaction failed');
                require PAGE_PATH . 'payments/transaction-failed.php';
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            log_error('Exception in processTrasactionPayment()', $e);
            require PAGE_PATH . 'payments/transaction-failed.php';
        }
    }

    // some code...
}
```

The multiple connections are checked with `connection_aborted()` and caching but not working as expected. The first request is passed to `$this->paymentService->processTrasactionPayment($transactionId, $publicToken);` and the subsequent requests are logged by `log_info("Transaction already processed for Public Token: {$publicToken}");` or `log_info("Multiple Connection Aborted for Public Token: {$publicToken}");` but when the first request is complete, the pages in `processTrasactionPayment()` are not getting loaded. Don't know where the issue lies.

Please help.

Comment: I don't see the use of `connection_aborted` making much sense here. What if the first request has already reached your server, and processing has proceeded beyond that point already, before the user clicks the second time? Then the first connection only gets aborted, _after_ you already performed that check.

Comment: @CBroe any suggestion on how to handle this problem?

Comment: You could set a session variable with a limited expiry, and check that the code only continues if it is not set.

Comment: @JacobMulquin This kind of check with the help of the cache is already there.

Comment: Ah indeed it is, my mistake. So when you say they are getting loaded, does `log_info("processTrasactionPayment() initiated"` get triggered at all?

Comment: @JacobMulquin Yes, for the first request, `log_info("processTrasactionPayment() initiated")` is triggered. and for the other subsequent requests, `log_info("Multiple Connection Aborted for Public Token: {$publicToken}");` or `log_info("Transaction already processed for Public Token: {$publicToken}");` is triggered. But when the first request is executed successfully, the `require` page code is not showing, and the screen is blank (I guess the frontend is entertaining the last request and not getting the response of the first request)

Comment: Interesting, so `log_info("Success page loaded.");` is triggered, but the pages do not display? If so then it definitely sounds like something in the caching mechanism is getting confused. Is there a way to temporarily disable it for testing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254090/discussion-between-aakash-martand-and-jacob-mulquin).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if using `connection_aborted()` gives you a valid result for what you are trying to do. Every time a user clicks on the Done button they are being sent to your server and every time the server creates a new process which is not aware of the existence of other processes on the server. To avoid this issue you can define a flag for every URL generated by the third party service and save it in the session, upon returning you can change the flag value and check whether it's changed before as an indicator of whether they have clicked on the button multiple times.

Also do consider conveying this in the UI before taking them to the third party website.